# Reverse the order of elements by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Say I have a DataFrame like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

which looks like this

```py
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
4  2  5
5  2  6
6  2  7
7  2  8
```

I would like to reverse its elements *within each group*, where column `a` determines the group. So, the desired output would be

```py
   a  b
0  1  4
1  1  3
2  1  2
3  1  1
4  2  8
5  2  7
6  2  6
7  2  5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you can pass a list of boolean to ascending: `df.sort_values(['a','b'],ascending=[True,False])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should achieve what the OP wants, which is to reverse(not to sort) the order of b for each a.

```
(
    df.groupby('a', sort=False)
    .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::-1])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

df.sort_values(by=['b'], ascending=False).sort_values(by=['a'], ascending=True)
```

Comment: No need to sort twice, pass a and b as a list and set ascending descending ... just like in sql

Answer (score 1):

`df = df.sort_values(by='b', ascending=False).sort_values(by='a')`

#### minimilistic version: (credits to pyd)

`df.sort_values(['a','b'],ascending=[True,False])`

Answer (score 0):

`df.sort_values(['a','b'],ascending=[True,False])`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I might have been unclear in the question - I was hoping to reverse the order that the elements appear in, not sort by them.

This seems to work:

```py
        reversed_ = df.copy()
        def reversing(x):
            x['a'] = x['a'].iloc[::-1].to_numpy()
            return x
        reversed_ = reversed_.groupby('group').apply(reversing)
        df['reversed_a'] = reversed_['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values(['a','b'], ascending = [True, False])
```

[Hello Kindly check here for further explanation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)